# Run sudo -s inside shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a shell script that installs and configures a log centralizing program called logentries. They have instructions on their website to copy and paste some lines into your command line which completes this process. I tried copying and pasting these exact bash commands into a shell script so I can just run the one script instead of copying and pasting all their instructions.

Here's the contents of my script:

```
sudo -s
echo "sudod"
tee /etc/yum.repos.d/logentries.repo <<EOF
[logentries]
name=Logentries repo
enabled=1
metadata_expire=1d
baseurl=http://rep.logentries.com/amazonlatest/\$basearch
gpgkey=http://rep.logentries.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-logentries
EOF
yum update
yum install logentries
```

I inserted the echo statement on line 2 to test if the script was even getting to that point, but when I run the script that doesn't even get outputted. I guess that means I can't just use `sudo -s` inside a script like I can on the command line.

Does anyone know how I can make these command line instructions execute in a shell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every command in a shell script, is run independently. The script is parent process which invokes commands as child processes. Thus, `sudo -s` creates a new process that opens root shell. However, this process cannot execute the commands later.

*You can also see your echo output being printed, if you do `exit` from root shell. This happens because, when you exit, the process of root shell gets terminated.*

You can write all the commands, except `sudo -s` in shell script. Make it executable by `chmod +x install_logentries.sh`. And execute it via `sudo install_logentries.sh`

Another alternative is to embed commands as a child process using << (as given below):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -s << SCRIPT
tee /etc/yum.repos.d/logentries.repo <<EOF

[logentries]
name=Logentries repo
enabled=1
metadata_expire=1d
baseurl=http://rep.logentries.com/amazonlatest/\$basearch
gpgkey=http://rep.logentries.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-logentries

EOF
yum update
yum install logentries
SCRIPT
```

Comment: Typo in sudo line.  I think you mean sudo -s, not sudo - s.

Answer (score 3):

I generally check the EUID and if it's not zero, then something like:

```
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
    exec sudo $0
done
```

(Basically force the script to run as root if it's not already.  The "exec" bit makes sure that control does not return to your non-root script.)

Answer (score 2):

Removing the sudo line and invoking it as `sudo ./script` should give you what you want.

Or, sudo could be used within the script by prefixing the individual commands (`sudo tee`, `sudo yum`).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'shebang' line (first line) to call your `bash`, as the following example shows:  (do a `which bash` to find where your `bash` is located as it may not be `/bin/bash`)

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -s
echo "sudod"
tee /etc/yum.repos.d/logentries.repo <<EOF
[logentries]
name=Logentries repo
enabled=1
metadata_expire=1d
baseurl=http://rep.logentries.com/amazonlatest/\$basearch
gpgkey=http://rep.logentries.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-logentries
EOF
yum update
yum install logentries
```

NOTE: You may be prompted when you do `sudo -s` for a password.

Comment: This doesn't actually work: the later commands don't run until after `sudo` has exited and has no further effect.